# Repeated sampling until condition

Tags: r, conditional-statements, sampling

I am looking to sample repeatedly from a distribution with a specific condition.
I am sampling 50 values for four iterations and saving the results. However I need each individual results from the iteration to be smaller than the last result at the same position.

```
mu.c <- c(7,6,5,3) # Means of control chains

chains.sim <- function(vector, N) {
  all.list <- list()
  
  for (i in 1:length(vector)) { 
    Y <- MASS::rnegbin(n = N, mu = vector[i], theta = 4)
    name <- paste('position:',i, sep = '')
    all.list[[name]] <- Y
  }
  all.list
}

chains.sim(mu.c, 50)
```

The sampling part works fine, but the Y individual results are of course not always smaller than the results from the previous iteration ("position").

Is there a way to repeat the sampling process until the result is smaller?

I would really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would add a while loop inside your for loop which samples data sets until the condition is met.

```
mu.c <- c(7,6,5,3) # Means of control chains

chain.sim <- function(vector, N) {
  all.list <- list()
  all.list[[1]] <- MASS::rnegbin(n = N, mu = vector[1], theta = 4)
  
  for (i in 2:length(vector)) { 
    is_smaller <- FALSE
    while(!is_smaller){
      Y <- MASS::rnegbin(n = N, mu = vector[i], theta = 4)
      if (all(all.list[[i-1]] >= Y)) is_smaller <- TRUE
    }
    all.list[[i]] <- Y
  }
  all.list
}
chain.sim(mu.c, 3)
```

Note that I changed the condition to `>=`, because if 0 is generated in any round, it will never find smaller values. Also, with 50 elements this code will never stop, because it is really unlikely to get two samples where each value is smaller, let alone 4 different samples.

Edit:
it can be much faster by sampling individually as you pointed out

```
chain.sim <- function(vector, N) {
  
  all.list <- list()
  all.list[[1]] <- MASS::rnegbin(n = N, mu = vector[1], theta = 4)
  
  for (i in 2:length(vector)) { 
    Y <- numeric(N)
    for (j in 1:N){
      previous_value <- all.list[[i-1]][j]
      if (previous_value == 0){
        Y[j] = 0
        next
      }
      is_smaller <- FALSE
      while(!is_smaller){
        val <- MASS::rnegbin(1, mu = vector[i], theta = 4)
        if (val <= previous_value) is_smaller <- TRUE
        Y[j] <- val
      }
    }

    all.list[[i]] <- Y
  }
  all.list
}
chain.sim(mu.c, 50)
```

If 0 is encountered anywhere, no more simulation is necessary as we know the next value can only be 0. This makes the simulation much faster

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer! I think your solution works fine in some sense. I only need the individual positions in each list to be different. Basically, running your function 400 times with N=1 would do the trick.

Comment: You could also sample for each individual position  until it is smaller than the previous one

Comment: Yes, this is pretty much what I was trying to do :)

Comment: I don't think your second version works correctly unfortunately, but I can just ```replicate ``` your first function!

Comment: hmm, it does give me credible numbers, which part doesn't work for you?

Comment: Well the numbers do go up in later parts. Only the first two numbers seem to be correct.